# jQuery dynamically update input type range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tDkEW/1/

Code:

```
<input type="text" name="chance" id="chance" class="text" value="50">
<input type="range" id="chanceSlider" class="vHorizon" min="0.01" max="98" step="0.01" style="background-color: #00aec8; width: 50%;">

$('#chanceSlider').on('change', function(){
    $('#chance').val($('#chanceSlider').val());
});

$('#chance').on('keyup', function(){
    $('#chanceSlider').val($('#chance').val());
});
```

But i want the value of the input update dynamiclly when you click and move the "slider", without having to release the mouse from it.

**EDIT: I DON'T WANT TO USE JQUERY UI**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event to bind isn't "change", it ought to be "input."

Something like:

```
$('#chanceSlider').on('input', function(){
    $('#chance').val($('#chanceSlider').val());
});
```

Comment: thanks, and how can i do if i want the value to be an integer?

Comment: You'll want to use the "parseInt()" function. You'll have to parse the value from chanceSlider before you send it as the value to "chance"

Answer (score 0):

I thought you want to make a small slider... I have created *[it from great help from css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/)*

Hopefully it helps some one some day...

<kbd>***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fkUt/1/)***</kbd>

```
<div id="line">
    <hr/>
</div>
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="show">0</div>
```